# Trying to print out the decision tree for a forest from scikit-learn ensemble

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graphviz, scikit-learn

I am trying to print out the decision tree for a forest from scikit-learn ensemble: For example for a DecisionTreeClassifier, I would use:

```
from sklearn import tree  
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier( criterion ='entropy', max_depth = 3,    
min_samples_leaf = 
clf = clf.fit( X_train, y_train) #Input this to analyze the training set.

import pydot, StringIO
dot_data = StringIO.StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz( clf, out_file = dot_data,    
feature_names =[' age', 'sex', 'first_class', 'second_class', 'third_class'])
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data( dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png('visualtree.png') 
from IPython.core.display import Image
Image( filename =visualtree.png')
```

I tried a similar approach for Random Forest Regressor (see below and got an error)

```
# Fit regression model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rfr_1 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_depth=5)
rfr_1.fit(X, y)

from sklearn.ensemble import*
import pydot, StringIO
dot_data = StringIO.StringIO() 
ensemble.export_graphviz( rf1, out_file = dot_data,    
feature_names =[' Temperature', 'Translator Bacteria'])
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data( dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png('fish.png') 
from IPython.core.display import Image
```

Image( filename ='fish.png')

File "randomforestregressor.py", line 45, in 
ensemble.export_graphviz( rf1, out_file = dot_data,
NameError: name 'ensemble' is not defined

How would I accomplish this? thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The error message is pretty explicit:

`File "randomforestregressor.py", line 45, in ensemble.export_graphviz( rf1, out_file = dot_data,
NameError: name 'ensemble' is not defined`

You access a variable named `ensemble` in your script line 45 but you never define such a variable. In your case you probably intended that variable to point to the `sklearn.ensemble` package:

`from sklearn import ensemble`

However if you do this you will likely get an `AttributeError` as the `sklearn.ensemble` package does not have `export_graphviz` function.

Instead what you might want to do is generate one image per tree in the forest by iterating over the elements of the `rfr_1.estimators_` list and calling the `export_graphviz` method of the `sklearn.tree` package on each of those tree.

However in practice displaying the trees of a forest is very often useless. Practitioners typically build random forests with hundreds or thousands of trees to get a good predictive accuracy. In such cases, visually inspecting that many trees is impractical.

Comment: Well said Ogrisel! Taking another tact, say I want to try to illustrate a solution at a discrete point in time, e.g., the price for 5-passenger mid-size cars in January 2014, how would I display such an answer using random forests? Thanks, Chris

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about but this is probably unrelated to the original question nor to this answer, therefore should probably be asked in separate question rather than in the comments of this answer.

Comment: Please remove this question